# Why are apachefriends using bitnami for XAMPP

Tags: xampp, open-source, bitnami

Bitnami is a private company (https://pitchbook.com/profiles/company/56422-36)

Why is bitnami packaging the open source XAMPP depolyment for windows?

Comment: Don't know but I'm surprised too. This should be done by the community. Like Wamp or EasyPHP Devserver.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am a XAMPP maintainer and a Bitnami developer https://www.apachefriends.org/about.html

XAMPP and Bitnami joined forces on 2013, see the announcement at
https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=53214. Since then we have been working with the Apache Friends community to improve XAMPP installers. We also have been working on having the components up-to-date, we added support for Linux and Windows 64 bit, we released XAMPP add-ons to install web applications easily and more.

Any feedback to improve XAMPP installers or any contributions will be welcome!

Comment: Thanks, does this mean the bitnami installer is open source too?

Comment: Correct. XAMPP is a compilation of free software, it's free of charge and it's free to copy under the terms of the GNU General Public Licence. But it is only the compilation of XAMPP that is published under GPL. Please check every single licence of the contained products to get an overview of what is, and what isn't, allowed.